# Azure EasyAuth: Getting Unauthorized error when try to login with a Microsoft account

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

This has been baffling me for hours now, so I have been trying to get EasyAuth working using different providers.
I am using this on Azure Functions, so let's say my function address is

https://xxx.azurewebsites.net

If I want to login into the service using a Google account I send my post request along with token received from Google to the following address

https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google

This gives me a converted token back.

However if I do the same thing with a Microsoft account using the following details

Request Body:

```
{ "access_token": "token-string-value" }
```

Endpoint:

https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount

It gives me the following error instead of a converted token

401 Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

--

I am using Msal JavaScript library to get my authentication token. Also I am testing these in Postman which makes it easy to understand what the problem is before I deal with the code and other stuff.

-- ***Update 1.0***

This does seem like a bug, as even if I try to navigate to the

https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount

It shows me the following
[image]

This URL works for other providers, Google, Facebook and Twitter. For all of them it redirects the user to the provider's login page.

According to the error page and the address bar contents, the client doesn't exist which could be referring to the application created on Azure to allow my website access the API. But everything has been setup correctly.
It would be helpful if someone from Azure We App Services can take a look at this.
I have created the Application and added the application ID and Secret int eh App Services page.

[image]

-- ***Update 2.0***

So after hours of investigation, I managed to get the URL working, shockingly it was due to wrong information given on Azure portal. The link in Authorization and Authentication section of App Service is pointing to a new platform to register applications, which is purely for Azure AD based users. 
For the external users to be able to login the application need to be registered in the following portal

https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

After registering the application here, and added the details in the App Service blade, the URL to EasyAuth is working.
However this doesn't resolve my issue. I still need a JavaScript library that gives me valid token which I can pass to EasyAuth endpoint.

Strangely the token taken from MSAL is not valid for Microsoft account. It just gives me the same error that my access is unauthorised. This means I probably need to use a different library to get a different token. I'd appreciate it if still someone can help me with this.

Below is a short sample code I am using to retrieve token and pass it to another function n which call EasyAuth endpoint and post the token along.

```
var applicationConfig = {
    clientID: "xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9fc1061d-5e26-4fd5-807e-bd969d857223",
    graphScopes: ["user.read"],
    graphEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
};

var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, acquireTokenRedirectCallBack,
    { storeAuthStateInCookie: true, cacheLocation: "localStorage" });

function signIn() {
    myMSALObj.loginPopup(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (idToken) {
        //Login Success
        acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph();

    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

function signOut() {
    myMSALObj.logout();
}

function acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph() {
    //Call acquireTokenSilent (iframe) to obtain a token for Microsoft Graph
    myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (accessToken) {

        // accessToken 

    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find what was causing the problem.
So basically only Live Connect SDK generated tokens are valid on

https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount

We were using MSAL which was generating tokens valid only on Azure Active Directory. I have been in touch with Azure Support, and have asked them to update the documentation. It currently is very confusing as none of these have been explained in the EasyAuth documentations.

We decided to go with Azure AD B2C, as it's more reliable and turns out cheaper for us. 
In case anyone would like to use EasyAuth with Microsoft Account, the following is showing how to get access token from Live SDK

```
    WL.Event.subscribe("auth.login", onLogin);

    WL.init({
        client_id: "xxxxxx",
        redirect_uri: "xxxxxx",
        scope: "wl.signin",
        response_type: "token"
    });

    WL.ui({
        name: "signin",
        element: "signin"
    });


    function onLogin(session) {
        if (!session.error) {

            var access_token = session.session.access_token;
            mobileClient.login('microsoftaccount', { 'access_token': access_token }, false)
                .then(function () {
                    console.log('TODO - could enable/disable functionality etc')
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(`ERROR: ${error}`);
                });

        }
        else {
            console.log(`ERROR: ${session.error_description}`);
        }
    }
```

Reference to

< script src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js">